# How to get url value with JS?

Tags: javascript

Running  with url like :

```
siteurl.com/items/4/editor
```

How can I value “4” value with js script(no jquery or any other libs) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: yes, I know how str.split works - I can not this string url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Comment: No, Window.location returns underfined.  location.search works for url like :  ?a=1. I have php/laravel url

Comment: @mstdmstd use `window.location.pathname`

Comment: if window.location is undefined then window.location.pathname will throw an undefined error

Answer (score 1):

`$currentURL = URL::current();` should return the URL.

Then you can apply

```php
currentURL.split('/')[3]
```